# How can I unlock Adventure mode?

Tags: diablo-iii

I started to play season 2 weeks ago and my season char is by far the best char I ever had.

Yesterday I tried to play Adventure with my non-season one, but I realized I haven't finished the game. My question is, is there an ease/fast way to finish it?

My non-seasons are pretty weak, I have a lvl 40~ and I thought I had finished the game before, but I don't have access to Adventure, maybe I've finished to much time ago, not sure if it's a thing, I don't know since when we have adventures.

Comment: Please try to limit questions to one per.  That will help get focused answers.

Comment: that's right.. mb

Comment: Thorn damage is damage you deal to melee or ranged opponents when they hit you
http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Thorns_(Diablo_III)

Comment: Also, I think it was Season 14 that started when this question was asked...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To unlock Adventure Mode you need to complete Act V in story mode first. You also need to unlock it separately for different type of characters - Normal and Hardcore.

If you finished the game before Act V release, then you need to go through Act V.

If you are playing solo, the fastest way to do the story is to set difficulty to Normal and just rush through the game skipping all cutscenes. There are speedrun achievements to complete each act in 1 hour, you can aim for them too.

If you have friend who plays D3 on the same platform you can ask them for help ([source](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/d3/topic/20753346693)):

> Ask someone who already completed story mode to create a game on last quest in Act 5 and invite you. When you kill Malt you will get your Adventure mode unlocked. You can do it on Normal - difficulty doesn't matter.

See [Adventure Mode](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Adventure_Mode)

Comment: hmm so the secret here is the Act V, I didn't know that... and thanks for the tip to unlock it, I'll do that, I'll ask my friend to create a game on Act 5... thank you very much mate